# Can we get radiobuttonList.Items.Count in .aspx page

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Can we get the count of total radiobuttonlist items from .aspx page. I have to call a javascript function onclientclick of a button and i want to loop through the total number of radiobuttonlist items. So can anyone tell me that can we get it from .aspx page. Because in my scenario i can not use code behind for this.

```
function ClearRBL() {
     for (i = 0; i < RBLCOUNT; i++) {
         document.getElementById('rblWorkerList_' + [i]).checked = false;
     }
}
```

How can i get RBLCOUNT here from .aspx page only? If not possible then in Javascript please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just created a javascript function as mentioned by Karthik Harve and found the total number of rows generated dynamically as below: -

```
function ClearRBL() {
 var rblLen = document.getElementById('rblWorkerList');
 for (i = 0; i < rblLen.rows.length; i++) {
 document.getElementById('rblWorkerList_' + [i]).checked = false;
 }
 }
```

It's working on both Mozila and IE.

**Thanks alot to all who tried to help.**

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how the aspx side would work, but if you want to do it just in JavaScript you could do something like the following that doesn't need to know the total number of elements in advance:

```
function ClearRBL() {
   var i = 0,
       rbl;

   while (null != (rbl = document.getElementById('rblWorkerList_' + i++)))
      rbl.checked = false;
}
```

The above assumes that the element ids end in numbers beginning with 0 counting up by 1s; the while loop will keep going until document.getElementById() doesn't find a matching element (in which case it returns null). A less cryptic way of writing it is as follows:

```
function ClearRBL() {
   var i = 0,
       rbl = document.getElementById('rblWorkerList_' + i);

   while (null != rbl) {
      rbl.checked = false;
      i++;
      rbl = document.getElementById('rblWorkerList_' + i);
   }
}
```

P.S. When the while loop finishes `i` will be equal to the number of radio buttons, which may be useful if you want to do something with that number afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:- This is not exactly what you want but hope it will help you.

```
function GetRBLSelectionID(RadioButtonListID) {
var RB1 = document.getElementById(RadioButtonListID);
var radio = RB1.getElementsByTagName("input");
var isChecked = false;
var retVal = "";
for (var i = 0; i < radio.length; i++) {
    if (radio[i].checked) {
        retVal = radio[i].id;
        break;
    }
}
return retVal;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

you can give a name all radio button and  then get them like this.

```
var RBLCOUNT= document[groupName].length;
```

or

```
 var RBLCOUNT= 0;
 var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
  for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; ++i) {
  if(inputs[i].type =="radio"){
     RBLCOUNT++;
     }
  }
```